# Check Cells - If Cell 2 have contains Specific different text then stop from saving

Tags: vba, macros, validation

I'm new to vba and have been figuring things as I need them. Any help or clue would be greatly apperiated!
I have a new requirement for my macro. I have a Macro that will copy a ws, create a file name, save the excel as an csv and re-open the csv. before the save as I need to make sure that two cells (A2 and F3) do not contain certain text. I would need this in VBA

Check if A2 contains "Project Name", 
If Yes, then show msg "supply project name" 
If No, then else Continue
check if F2 contains "# XXXX", 
If Yes show msg "Enter Number", 
If No Save (or continue the macro)

```
For Each cell In Range("A2,F3")
If cell.Value = "Project Name" Then
      Cancel = True
      If Cancel Then MsgBox "You will need to Enter a Project Name before saving", vbOKOnly, "Needs a Project Name"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "# XXXX" Then
    If Cancel Then MsgBox "Please Enter a Number", vbOKOnly, "Needs a number"

End If
```

Here is my Macro I would insert the validation before save

```
Dim FileName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet


'Creates New FileName - Concatenates username and Desktop path with for New Name
    NewName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & Range("B2").Value & " - JIRA Import" & ".CSV"

'Makes a copy of the Worksheet
    ws.Copy

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


<<-- Validataion would go Here-->>

'Save Worksheet as a CSV File
    Debug.Assert Not ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=NewName, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

'Removes List of Names from People Picker
    Range("G50:G64").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Shows user a message
    MsgBox "File saved to Desktop for JIRA Import " & vbNewLine & NewName

'Closes CSV files
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Reopens CSV File Without Macro - Clean CSV
  Application.Workbooks.Open (NewName)

  FileExist = False
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. Below is my code

```
If Range("A2").Value = "Project Name" Then
    Range("A2").Interior.Color = vbCyan
    MsgBox "Please provide Project Name Before Saving"
    Exit Sub
Else
Set fnd = Range("F3").Find("xx")
If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
    Range("F3").Interior.Color = vbCyan
    MsgBox "Please provide Number and Name"
Exit Sub
End If
End If
```